# TCP Client - Receive message from unknown / unlimited size

Tags: c, tcpclient, c99

I am currently sitting at a university task and am facing a problem that cannot be solved for me. I'm developing a TCP client which connects to a server and gets a message from there.

The client should be able to work with strings of any length and output all received characters until the server closes the connection.

My client works and with a fixed string length, I can also receive messages from e.g. djxmmx.net port 17. However, I have no idea how to map this arbitrary length.

My C knowledge is really poor, which is why I need some suggestions, ideas or tips on how to implement my problem.

Actual this is my code for receiving messages:

```
// receive data from the server
    char server_response[512];
    recv(client_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0);
```

Comment: You say 'TCP'; I'm taking you at your word that this is not UDP.  (The rules change!) . One aspect is that you'll need to capture the actual length of the received message from the return value: `int length = recv(…);`.  For the rest, if you get a single message to read, then you `recv()` iteratively until EOF.  If you have multiple messages in each direction, you have to know where the message boundaries are, somehow.

Comment: Yeah it's tcp (SOCK_STREAM). And the int length ... makes sense to me, but how can I use recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
without the size_t len? So this is the length or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to work with input of essentially unlimited length, you will need to call `recv()` several times in a loop to get each succeeding section of the input. If you can deal with each section at a time, and then discard it and move onto the next section, that's one approach. If you are going to need to process all the input in one go, you're going to have to find a way of storing arbitrarily large amounts of data, probably using dynamic memory allocation.

With `recv()` you will probably want to loop reading content until it returns `0` indicating that the socket has performed an orderly shutdown ([documentation here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html)). That might look something like this:

```
char server_response[512];
ssize_t bytes_read;
while ((bytes_read = recv(client_socket, &server_response,
                          sizeof(server_response), 0)) > 0) {
  /* do something with the data of length bytes_read
     in server_response[] */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Receiving in "steps" is ok for me and works so far too, but I can't manage to build a string dynamically.

Comment: You're welcome - glad it works. Feel free to mark the answer as "accepted" and vote it up if you think it's a good answer.

Comment: Dynamic memory management is really useful, but needs to be done right. You'll need to create a space to put your data into, and if it gets filled up, either a) make that space bigger, or b) find a new, bigger space, and move your existing data to it. There are already some questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management?sort=votes&pageSize=50): Do have a go at getting it right, and then ask another question here if you need help. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. In the meantime I found a good tutorial and my client is now doing what it should.